# Pytest Repeatedly Run Tests Session with Pytest-order

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to repeatedly run the entire pytest tests session (e.g. *123123*) and not just repeat the individual tests (e.g. *112233*) when using pytest-order?

The pytest-repeat documention states

> "you can use --repeat-scope command line option ... session scope repeats whole tests session, i.e. all collected tests executed once, then all such tests executed again and etc."
> (https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/)

But this doesn't seem to be the case when also using pytest-order's `@pytest.mark.order`.

I tried using pytest-repeat's `--repeat-scope session` but get *112233*. When `@pytest.mark.order` is not present, the expected *123123* is output.

With pytest-order:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.order(1)
def test_one():
    assert False, "1"

@pytest.mark.order(2)
def test_two():
    assert False, "2"
    
@pytest.mark.order(3)
def test_three():
    assert False, "3"
```

Running this test outputs *112233*:

```
C:\Python>pytest test_repeat.py --no-header --tb=no --count 2 --repeat-scope session 
...
======================== short test summary info ========================
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_one[1-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_one[2-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_two[1-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_two[2-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_three[1-2] - AssertionError: 3
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_three[2-2] - AssertionError: 3
======================== 6 failed in 0.03s ========================
```

---

Without pytest-order:

```
import pytest

def test_one():
    assert False, "1"

def test_two():
    assert False, "2"
    
def test_three():
    assert False, "3"
```

Outputs the expected *123123*

```
======================== test session starts ========================
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_one[1-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_two[1-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_three[1-2] - AssertionError: 3
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_one[2-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_two[2-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat.py::test_three[2-2] - AssertionError: 3
======================== 6 failed in 0.04s ========================
```

---

Unfortunately removing pytest-order from the actual code isn't an option for me, so I have been stuck manually rerunning the tests session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the order in which the plugins are called.
`pytest-ordering` wants to be the last plugin to be called, to make sure that the ordering is done after any other plugin that also may change the order.

This behavior can be disabled by using the option [--indulgent-ordering](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#indulgent-ordering). If using this together with a session repeat scope (as mentioned in the question), `pytest-repeat` will run after `pytest-order` and therefore be able to repeat the tests in the desired order:

```
C:\Python>pytest test_repeat.py --count 2 --repeat-scope session --no-header --tb=no --indulgent-ordering
...
===================== short test summary info ==========================
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_one[1-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_two[1-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_three[1-2] - AssertionError: 3
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_one[2-2] - AssertionError: 1
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_two[2-2] - AssertionError: 2
FAILED test_repeat_order.py::test_three[2-2] - AssertionError: 3
====================== 6 failed in 0.08s ================================
```

*Disclaimer:* I'm the maintainer of `pytest-order`.